# Setting Google Credentials with Flask and Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, youtube-data-api

I have an app which incidentally uses public `youtube API` data, not user-related.

> **STAGE 1**: **Running from command line**

At the top of my `youtube_module.py`, I had:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
CREDENTIALS = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
```

as documentation requires, at `.bashrc` I set:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/credentials.json
```

api calls were succesful and everything worked.

> **STAGE 2**: **Running with Flask and Gunicorn**.

Now I'm testing the app on the browser. When I run the `Flask` app (`Listening at: 127.0.0.1:5000`) via `Gunicorn` with `$ gunicorn app:app --workers 16` (`Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000`)

the app serves a few pages but then encounters the following error:

```
ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

**`credentials.json` were on the same path, however.**

How do I correctly set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` within `Flask`?

Answer (score 2):

setting credentials inside `Flask` `app.py` code works, like so:

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "path_to_your_.json_credential_file"
```